# How to check if value exists in multidimensional array and return that array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out how to write a function that will do two things.

1. search a multidimensional array for a specific value (easy)
2. return the array that has the value within it.

I've been searching all weekend, and I got close, but this thing is kicking my butt.

here's my array:

```
$keys = array(
'core'    => array(
    'key'       => 'key1',
    'directory' => "$core_dir/"
),
'plugins' => array(
    'key'       => 'key2',
    'directory' => "$core_dir/plugins/"
),
'themes'  => array(
    'key'       => 'key3',
    'directory' => "$core_dir/$themes_dir/",
    'theme'     => array(
        'theme1' => array(
            'key'       => 'theme_key1',
            'directory' => "$core_dir/$themes_dir/theme1/"
        ),
        'theme2'     => array(
            'key'       => 'theme_key2',
            'directory' => "$core_dir/$themes_dir/theme2/"
        )
    )
),

'hooks'   => 'hook_key'
);
```

so is I search for `key1` it will return the `core` array.
if I search for `theme_key1` it will return the `theme1` array.

here's the function I have so far: (stitched it together from allot of reading and another function I found online).

```
function search_in_array($srchvalue, $array){
global $theme_key, $ext_key;

if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0){
    $foundkey = array_search($srchvalue, $array);

    if ($foundkey === FALSE){

        foreach ($array as $key => $value){
            if (is_array($value) && count($value) > 0){
                $foundkey = search_in_array($srchvalue, $value);


                if ($foundkey != FALSE){
                    if(isset($_GET['th'])){

                        $theme_array = $value;

                        return $theme_array;
                    }else{
                        return $value;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        return $foundkey;
}
```

}

Comment: and what is the issue, doesn't the function work?

Comment: it does not, it returns the `themes` array but I need it to go down one more level so that I can get the array for `theme1`. eventually I will have different themes in the array so if I search for `theme_key7` I need to be able to get the array for `theme7`. if that makes sense :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. search a multidimensional array for a specific value (easy) return
> 2. the array that has the value within it.

Short solution using `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, `RecursiveArrayIterator` and `iterator_to_array` function:

```
$search_value = 'theme_key2';
$it = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($keys));
$arr = [];
foreach ($it as $v) {
    if ($v == $search_value) {
        $arr = iterator_to_array($it->getInnerIterator());
        break;
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [key] => theme_key2
    [directory] => <your custom variable values here -> $core_dir/$themes_dir>/theme2/
)
```

Comment: wow, this is super interesting. I've never even heard of `RecursiveIteratorIterator` nor `RecursiveArrayIterator`. gonna look those up

Comment: @GeneralCan, yes, sometimes they can be very useful

Answer (score 1):

Don't complicate it too much. You can make use of recursive function to go deeper into nested arrays.

```
function return_array($arr, $value) {
    $arr_found = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $arr_value) {
        if(is_array($arr_value)) {
            if(in_array($value, $arr_value)) {
                return array($key => $arr_value);
            }
            $arr_found = return_array($arr_value, $value);
        } else {
            if($arr_value == $value) {
                $arr_found = array($key => $arr_value);
            }
        }
    }

    return $arr_found;
}

echo "<p>" . var_dump(return_array($keys, 'key1')) . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . var_dump(return_array($keys, 'theme_key1')) . "</p>";
```

Hope it helps!